# Guidance for how to add nicely formatted output to a custom rails generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, generator

Like the title says - I want to add my custom output to a rails generator - much like you see `identical - xxx` or `force - xxx`

I want to add special, nicely formatted warnings for my custom generator - only I don't see any guidance for doing that, other than using `puts`

For example, I'd like to see:

```
 Warining: Missing Related Data File
```

Where the word warning would be written  in red.  Very similar to what you see in a typical rails generator command...

Comment: Can you be more specific about what kind of formatting you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails' generators are based on [Thor](https://github.com/wycats/thor/wiki). When you raise a `Thor::Error` the output will automatically be colored red. For example:

```
raise Error, "Warning: Missing related data file"
```

This will color the whole message red (and suppress the backtrace for cleaner output).

Furthermore you can use any of Thor's [actions](http://rdoc.info/github/wycats/thor/master/Thor/Shell/Basic) in your generator and several, e.g. `say` and `yes?`, support a second `color` argument, allowing you to do e.g.:

```
say_status "OK", "Blue is my favorite color", :blue
```

The available colors are [shown here](https://github.com/wycats/thor/blob/master/lib/thor/shell/color.rb#L53).

Finally, you can call [`set_color`](http://rdoc.info/github/wycats/thor/master/Thor/Shell/Color#set_color-instance_method) directly for fine-grained control of formatting, e.g.:

```
say set_color( "STOP ",    :red ) +
    set_color( "CAUTION ", :yellow ) +
    set_color( "GO!",      :green, true )
```

(If the third parameter is true the output will be bold.)

I hope that's helpful—but please use it responsibly!

Comment: Thanks - That works.  I started using `colorize` (which is great and does does what I want) but this seems a bit more 'native'...